# What happens if pthread_key_delete is called on a key after a failed pthread_key_create?

Tags: pthreads, posix, pthread-key-create

Suppose the following code:

```c
pthread_key_t key;
pthread_key_create(&key, NULL);    /* failure here */
pthread_key_delete(key);
```

If `pthread_key_create` fails, is the call to `pthread_key_delete` considered *undefined behavior*? How about if `pthread_key_create` is commented out?

The [pthread_key_delete](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/pthread_key_delete.html) section of the POSIX standard states:

> The pthread_key_delete() function shall delete a thread-specific data key previously returned by pthread_key_create().

Since `pthread_key_delete` expects a thread-specific data key *previously returned* by `pthread_key_create`, I'm afraid calling `pthread_key_delete` on a key that was not returned by `pthread_key_create` can lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is implicitly undefined behavior, to the extent that the standard you link doesn't define what happens in that use case.

The SUSv7, however, *is* explicit in its discussion of `pthread_key_delete`, saying plainly in its [CHANGE HISTORY for Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_key_delete.html#tag_16_434) that:

> The [EINVAL] error for a key value not obtained from pthread_key_create() or a key deleted with pthread_key_delete() is removed; this condition results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Oh dear, I just realized I read the older *Issue 6* whereas I had intended to read the more current *Issue 7*. I must keep a watchful eye next time.

Comment: @VilhelmGray, fair enough.  I'd argue that it's the same undefined behavior in either, just that SUSv7 is more explicit about it.

Comment: Yes, I believe that probably factored into the decision to explicitly state there is undefined behavior in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the source code of [pthread_key_create](https://github.com/jschmidlapp/pthreads-emb/blob/master/pthread_key_create.c) and [pthread_key_delete](https://github.com/jschmidlapp/pthreads-emb/blob/master/pthread_key_delete.c)
it seems that pthread_key_create is returning a memory location and filling in other fields of "key" structure, which is opaque like everything else in posix.

pthread_key_delete expects the key structure fields to be populated/set with valid data to search for the memory location. So it seems calling pthread_key_delete after a failed pthread_key_create causes undefined behavior. Here is one more link that seems to support by opinion.

[How does pthread_key_t and the method pthread_key_create work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005955/how-does-pthread-key-t-and-the-method-pthread-key-create-work)

I hope this helps.

Comment: The source base you selected as example might not be the most widly spread implemention of Pthread in terms of usage, wouln't it?

Comment: Also, the code for `pthread_key_delete()` linked does not fully comply with the POSIX specification. For example it will not return `EINVAL` if a zeroed out `pthread_key_t` key had been passed in, nor if the key had not been found.

Comment: Below you can see two more examples for pthread_key_delete.c http://code.mjdsystems.ca/p/equalizer/source/tree/580548b8250b734cdad16caaa0b47d4916ea21c9/Windows/pthreads/src/pthread_key_delete.c and ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/sources/pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release/pthread_key_delete.c None of them return EINVAL. However, there are some implementations that do return EINVAL. For instance : http://cristi.indefero.net/p/uClibc-cristi/source/tree/0949826e9501e9f08767aeb476ea1464bf95f218/libpthread/nptl/pthread_key_delete.c So, this proves that behaviour is "undefined".

Comment: For `eglibc` the behaviour would be defined and `EINVAL` would be returned. No key would provoke UB. However, I do agree that do calling `pthread_key_delete()` on an undefined key is a bad idea, although the standard (as linked by my answer) does not explicitly mentions this.

Comment: I'm skeptical of the appropriateness of looking at any implementation to determine whether a usage is undefined behavior or not.  Whether or not the behavior is undefined has everything to do with the specification of behaviors and not their particular implementations.

Comment: @pilcrow i agree. looking at the implementation was my last resort, since it was not mentioned explicitely.

Comment: @pilcrow: Agreed! However, it is interesting to see how implementations differ ...